# Group results after join?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, group-by

So, I have three tables. `Movies`, `movies_genres` and `genres`. I want to get a movie by its Id, and also join its genres in the result. I managed to join the results, but it doesn't display as i want it to. I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible.

This is my query:

```
SELECT `movies`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(genres.id) AS genre_id, GROUP_CONCAT(genres.name) AS genre_name
FROM (`movies`)
INNER JOIN `movies_genres`
    ON `movies_genres`.`movie_id` = `movies`.`id`
INNER JOIN `genres`
    ON `genres`.`id` = `movies_genres`.`genre_id` WHERE `movies`.`id` = 19908
GROUP BY `movies`.`id`
```

The query was generated by Codeigniters Active Record class, here is the Codeigniter code if that helps:

```
$this->db->select('movies.*, GROUP_CONCAT(genres.id) AS genre_id, GROUP_CONCAT(genres.name) AS genre_name');
$this->db->from('movies');
$this->db->where('movies.id', $movie_id);
$this->db->join('movies_genres', 'movies_genres.movie_id = movies.id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('genres', 'genres.id = movies_genres.genre_id', 'inner');
$this->db->group_by('movies.id');
```

Here is the result i'm currently getting:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 19908
    [movie_title] => Zombieland
    [overview] => An easily spooked guy...
    [genre_id] => 28,12,35,27
    [genre_name] => Action,Adventure,Comedy,Horror
)
```

And this is what I want:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 19908
    [movie_title] => Zombieland
    [overview] => An easily spooked guy...
    [genres] => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => 28,
            'name' => Action
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 12,
            'name' => Adventure
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 35,
            'name' => Comedy
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 27,
            'name' => Horror
        )
    )
)
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you listed will have *n* rows (where *n* = # of movies) whereas the query it seems you want will have many more rows (# of movie_genre's entries).  You're probably better off leaving that query as it is, and doing some post processing.

Consider:

After you get it, just run your result (e.g. `$result`) array through something like:

```
foreach($result as &$row)
{
    // Split over commas
    $gi_elements = explode(',', $row['genre_id']);
    $gn_elements = explode(',', $row['genre_name']);

    // Build genre 
    $row['genre'] = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($gi_elements); $i++)
    {
        $row['genre'][] = array('id' => $gi_elements[$i], 'name' => $gn_elements[$i]);
    }

     // Cleanup
     unset($row['genre_id']);
     unset($row['genre_name']);
}
```

Afterwards, $results will look exactly as you wish without extra database work.

***EDIT:*** Fixed some typos.

Comment: That would work, and i have considered it already, but i wanted to see if there's any way to do it in the SQL query instead. Just to avoid unnecessary php code. But if it's not possible this'll work. :)

Comment: @qwerty.  Oh, ok.  Well then you should consider unchecking my answer.  People who might know whether codeigniter supports that kind of multi-level array generation might skip reading the question once they see its checked.

Comment: Oh that's true. Thanks for the tip! If nobody replies with a better answer in a few hours i'll mark yours as accepted again.