# more efficient way to join tables but produce nested results?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What is the most efficient way of achieving a result set like this in PHP with codeigniter active record?

```
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 12
        [title] => 2 sections
        [layout_id] => 1
        [layout] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [file] => 3_column.php
                [title] => 3 Column
            )

        [sections] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [module_id] => 12
                        [section_id] => 1
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [module_id] => 12
                        [section_id] => 2
                    )

            )

    )
```

Here is something that would give me the desired nested results, but I see some huge inefficiencies with this approach (disregard the `select *` for each query)

```
public function all()
{
  $rows = $this->db->get('modules')->result();

  foreach($rows as &$row)
  {
    $row->layout = $this->db->get_where('layouts', array('id' => $row->layout_id), 1)->first_row();
    $row->sections = $this->db->get_where('modules_sections', array('module_id' => $row->id))->result();
  }

  return $rows;
}
```

Comment: I'm not codeigniter expert, but I guess you won't achieve it - php/mysql doesn't offer such a functionality itself; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209264/php-mysql-group-results-after-join?rq=1 . You can select data at one query using joins, ordering by modules.id, and then create desired structure in one foreach loop; it might be faster, especially if your database is external, as it will be only one query, but it will take more memory, as it will duplicate layout and module row for each section. I wish somebody would know a better solution, but I guess it won't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily transform these several queries into one query using some joins and a GROUP_BY clause. The biggest downside to this approach is that it requires grouping and delimiting the data a little, but PHP is good at "exploding" delimited data. Try this out:

```
function all()
{

    $this->db->select("`modules`.*, CONCAT(`layouts`.`id`,'".DATA_SUBDELIMITER."',`layouts`.`title`,'".DATA_SUBDELIMITER."',`layouts`.`file`) AS layout, CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(`sections`.`id`,'".DATA_SUBDELIMITER."',`sections`.`title` SEPARATOR '".DATA_DELIMITER."') AS CHAR) AS sections", false);
    $this->db->from('modules');
    $this->db->join('layouts', 'layouts.id = modules.layout_id');
    $this->db->join('modules_sections', 'modules_sections.module_id = modules.id');
    $this->db->join('sections', 'sections.id = modules_sections.section_id');
    $this->db->group_by('modules.id');

    $rows = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    foreach($rows as &$row)
    {
        foreach($row as $k=>&$r)
        {
            if($k=='layout' || $k=='sections')
            {
                $new_r = explode(DATA_DELIMITER, $r);
                foreach($new_r as &$c)
                {
                    $e = explode(DATA_SUBDELIMITER,$c);
                    $c = array();
                    list($c['id'],$c['title']) = $e;
                    if(!empty($e[2])) $c['file'] = $e[2];
                }
                if($k=='layout') $new_r = $new_r[0];
                $r = $new_r;
            }
        }
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

This example uses DATA_DELIMITER and DATA_SUBDELIMITER for the characters that will delimit the data. If you use these constants then you should probably define them in your application/config/constants.php file. Perhaps like this:

```
define('DATA_DELIMITER','||');
define('DATA_SUBDELIMITER','##');
```

This code was tested to produce a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Module 1
            [layout_id] => 1
            [layout] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 3 Column
                    [id] => 1
                    [file] => 3_column.php
                )

            [sections] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 1
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 2
                            [id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Module 2
            [layout_id] => 2
            [layout] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 2 Column
                    [id] => 2
                    [file] => 2_column.php
                )

            [sections] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 1
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 3
                            [id] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Module 3
            [layout_id] => 1
            [layout] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 3 Column
                    [id] => 1
                    [file] => 3_column.php
                )

            [sections] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 3
                            [id] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => Module 4
            [layout_id] => 2
            [layout] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 2 Column
                    [id] => 2
                    [file] => 2_column.php
                )

            [sections] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 1
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 2
                            [id] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 3
                            [id] => 3
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Section 4
                            [id] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient is kind of a relative term here.

If you are looking at minimizing queries on the sql server you could always serialize your objects and store them in a cache table, then you'd only have one lookup, but you'd have to maintain those objects on any sort of write operation. Other than that, you probably just need to load test and see where the bottle necks are.  Sometimes multiple queries can be faster than a huge multi-table join.

Comment: I agree with you on the multiple queries can be faster, but also a bit more maintainable for someone not familiar with complex sql queries. In terms of efficiency I'm looking for a maintainable code approach using codeigniter's activerecord syntax that minimizes queries (compared to what i currently have). But additionally curious in a sql query that would produce nested results (outside of the ci ar syntax).

Comment: You can't really do nested results with sql because everything comes out as a flat table... You either do lots of queries or you join tables like crazy.  If you want super easy maintainable code, I'd move off of active record to an ORM like this: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/ The downside is it doesn't always produce the nicest sql.